# Excel Circular reference while using sum

Tags: excel, circular-reference

I have two columns A and B where one element in each of the column is a product of a constant value and the sum of all the elements in the other column, as below

A x1 | x2 | x3 =c1* sum(y1:y3)

B y1 | y2=c2*sum(x1:x3)| y3

When I have to sum the individual columns I am getting a circular reference for obvious reasons but I am not sure as to what to do to break the circular reference?

Attached is the image of the excel sheet i'm working on:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Q1R.png]

Comment: I think your columns should be D & E, not A & B

Comment: I'm lost as to what you're trying to accomplish, though - This causes an obvious circular reference... B relies on A relies on B.... What would you expect to have / want instead?